# This bundle is invalid - The Info.plist file for /Payload/MyAppName.app/Sticker Pack.stickerpack is missing or could not be read

Tags: ios, xcode, imessage, imessage-extension, ios-stickers

Hope you are well. 
I want to add iMessage Stickers to my app. 
My app created in Android Studio using LibGDX/RoboVM. So, I can't add Stickers extension directly to my project. I have signed .ipa as output from Android Studio after building with RoboVM.
I have created a single standalone project in Xcode with my app's bundle id, added the Stickers extension, then have done the following.

In the terminal

> 1. Unzipped the .ipa using "unzip MyApp.ipa".
> 2. Removed the _CodeSignature folder using "rm -rf Payload/MyApp.app/_CodeSignature/"
> 3. Copied and Pasted the Stickers extension to the "Payload/MyApp.app/"
> 4. Copied and Pasted the provisioning profile using "cp MyDistributionProfile.mobileprovision Payload/MyApp.app/embedded.mobileprovision"
> 5. Signed again using "codesign -f -s "iPhone Distribution: MyCompany INC" --entitlements Entitlements.plist Payload/MyApp.app"
> 6. Zipped using "zip -qr MyResignedApp.ipa Payload/".

After this, I tried to upload the MyResignedApp.ipa via ApplcationLoader from XCode and did not get any error during upload.

The problem is that I received the rejection email, where they said the following,

> This bundle is invalid - The Info.plist file for /Payload/MyApp.app/Sticker Pack.stickerpack is missing or could not be read.

The Info.plist exists and here is it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" 
 "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
<string>en</string>
<key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
<string>new_stickers</string>
<key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
<string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
<key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
<string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
<key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
<string>6.0</string>
<key>CFBundleName</key>
<string>$(PRODUCT_NAME_)</string>
<key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
<string>XPC!</string>
<key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
<string>1.0</string>
<key>CFBundleVersion</key>
<string>1</string>
<key>NSExtension</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExtensionPointIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.apple.message-payload-provider</string>
    <key>NSExtensionPrincipalClass</key>
    <string>StickerBrowserViewController</string>
</dict>
```

Any suggestions what I'm doing wrong?
Many Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You `Copied and Pasted the Stickers extension to the "Payload/MyApp.app/" but extension has to be located in "Payload/MyApp.app/PlugIns".

MobiVM natively supports packing and signing extension out of the box. And it is not required to manual repacking/signing.

But you have to build app extension in Xcode within standalone project, then reference extension in robovm.xml like bellow:

```
 <appExtensions>
     <extension profile="3AED05A9-5F1F-4120-9276-11980B9C88EE">OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension</extension>
 </appExtensions>
```

To build it in Xcode easies way is to add extension target to empty project. Then build it separately from command line using `xcode-build`:

```
xcodebuild -project onesignal.xcodeproj -target OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension -configuration release -sdk iphoneos -arch arm64 -arch armv7 -arch armv7s BUILD_DIR=build BUILD_ROOT=build
xcodebuild -project onesignal.xcodeproj -target OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension -configuration release -sdk iphonesimulator -arch i386 -arch x86_64 BUILD_DIR=build BUILD_ROOT=build
```

and pack into fat binary using `lipo`.

```
lipo -create -output "OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension.appex/OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension" \
    "build/release-iphoneos/OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension.appex/OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension" \
    "build/release-iphonesimulator/OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension.appex/OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension"
```

Also in case of stickers extension RoboVM copies following to IPA:

- MessagesApplicationExtensionSupport/MessagesApplicationExtensionStub
- MessagesApplicationSupport/MessagesApplicationStub

Which might be missing when you do repacking manually.

There is a [tutorial](https://dkimitsa.github.io/2018/01/18/tutorial-using-app-extensions-with-robovm/) for MobiVM how to use app extension which provide more details about each step.

Comment: Hello. Thank you a lot for your answer. Looking into it now. Will let you know updates. Thanks)

Comment: I have followed the steps that are in the tutorial.

In the last step, I have added the following to my Robovm.xml file.

  `<appExtensionPaths>
    <path>Plugins</path>
  </appExtensionPaths>
  <appExtensions>
    <extension>new_stickers</extension>
  </appExtensions>`

Now, what should I do? I'm not sure if I should just build my Robovm project, as I think, that I must do something with the new_stickers folder :D

Comment: I assume you have built you stickers extension and got `stickers.appex`. 
(btw, there is Stickers Pack App template in Xcode which make it event simpler to produce) 
Then in RoboVM:
1) <appExtensionPaths> <path> -- specifies location of `stickers.appex` in respect to project root, e.g. if you put it in `libs/` -- then specify just `<appExtensionPaths> <path>libs</path></appExtensionPaths>`
2) refer to it in section `<appExtensions> <extension>stickers</extension>  </appExtensions>`. May attention that its without .appex extension

Comment: then run it or create IPA as usual

Comment: That's worked @dkimitsa. Thank you a lot. Now I can run on my device and see the stickers. 
But, when I try to upload the .ipa to the TestFlight, I'm receiving the following Rejection message from Apple.

Invalid Messages Application Extension Support. The files MessagesApplicationExtensionStub don’t match myAPP.app/PlugIns/newstickers.appex/MessagesApplicationExtensionStub. Make sure the files are correct, rebuild your app, and resubmit it. Don’t apply post-processing to myAPP.app/PlugIns/newstickers.appex/MessagesApplicationExtensionStub.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what version of mobivm are you using ? Have tried with 2.3.6 and it was accepted for iTunes (And I did no manual repacking of ipa)

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you for your help.